# Able to commit in git but not able to push in git with ERROR: JIRA/RALLY_ID (USXXXX/DEXXXX/ESTC-XXXXX) is required in commit comment, not pushing

Tags: github

For a private project hosted in github, I am able to commit the message. I am unable to push the changes to remote. I get the following error. I have also tried with the command `git commit --amend -m "JiraId: Msg"` and after that I tried with the command `git push --force`. Still I always get the same below error message.

```
> remote: INFO: Checking commit message ...... remote: ERROR:
> JIRA/RALLY_ID (USXXXX/DEXXXX/ESTC-XXXXX) is required in commit
> comment, not pushing remote: TIPS: run git commit --amend to update
> commit comment and push again
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [pre-receive server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), which enforces you to use related issue key from Jira in the commit message, prior to pushing.

Jira is an issue tracker, and i'm assuming the work you are trying to push is described in a related issue (story, task...) in a Jira project.

Acceptable issue key format is: (USXXXX/DEXXXX/ESTC-XXXXX)

It may be one-of the above: `US1234` or `ESTC-9876`

Or all as one: `US1234/DEX5678/ESTC-3344`

May/not include parentheses - `(US1234)` or `(US1234/DEX5678/ESTC-3344)`

You probably need to update the commit message with the actual issue key before be able to push it successfully to remote.

Try to asking org/repo admins about it.

Give it a try if you have actual related issue keys.

Comment: I am also the admin, how can I change pre-receive server-side hook in github?

Comment: well, you have just used the right search prompt as a comment :)